# Change page layout for products under specific category

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, rwd-theme, design

I am trying to set `2columns-right.phtml` layout for products under specific category while the default is 1column.phtml.(Please note i don't want to change Category page layout but layouts of products under that category)

I tried Admin >Manage categories >Select Category >Custom design >Change "Apply to Products" to yes and in "Custom Layout Updates" entered

```
<reference name="product.info">
<action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-right.phtml</template></action>
</reference>
```

Didn't work

Then i went to `rwd/default/layout/catalog.xml` and added after

```
<!--
    Product view
    -->
```

Entered

```
<CATEGORY_3>
<reference name="product.info">
<action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-right.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
    </CATEGORY_3>
```

But even this didn't work, It would be of great help any ideas on this. Magento CE Version 1.9.1

Comment: product can be in multiple categories

Comment: yes but not in my case

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a small module

Your `config.xml` should looks like

`app/code/codePool/Package/Extension/etc/config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Package_Extension>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Package_Extension>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <events>
            <controller_action_layout_load_before>
                <observers>
                    <categoryhandle>
                        <class>Package_Extension_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>cateHandle</method>
                    </categoryhandle>
                </observers>
            </controller_action_layout_load_before>
        </events>
    </global>
</config>
```

Your observer should looks like

`app/code/codePool/Package/Extension/Model/Observer.php`

```
<?php
class Package_Extension_Model_Observer
{

    public function cateHandle(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $product = Mage::registry('current_product');

        /**
         * Return if it is not product page
         */
        if (!($product instanceof Mage_Catalog_Model_Product)) {
            return;
        }
        $category= 3;
        $categories=$product->getCategoryIds();
        if(in_array($category, $categories)){
            $update = $observer->getEvent()->getLayout()->getUpdate();
            $update->addHandle('PRODUCT_CATEGORY_'.$category);
        }

    }
}
```

And in your themes `local.xml` add below code or as you mention `rwd/default/layout/catalog.xml`  add below code

```
<PRODUCT_CATEGORY_3>
    <reference name="root">
      <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-right.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
</PRODUCT_CATEGORY_3>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `controller_action_layout_generate_xml_before` Event

```
<events>
    <controller_action_layout_generate_xml_before>
        <observers>
            <add_Customer_handler>
                <class><VENDOR_NAME>_<MODULE_NAME>_Model_Observer</class>
                <method>changeTemplate</method>
            </add_Customer_handler>
        </observers>
    </controller_action_layout_generate_xml_before>  
</events>
```

Observer

```
public function changeTemplate($observer)
{
    $action = $observer->getEvent()->getAction();
    $fullActionName = $action->getFullActionName();
    $category=<YOUR CATEGORY ID>;

    if($fullActionName=='catalog_product_view')
    {
      $product=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(Mage::registry('current_product')->getId());
      $categories=$product->getCategoryIds()();

      if(in_array($category, $categories);){
        $layout = $observer->getEvent()->getLayout();
        $update = $layout->getUpdate();
        $xml = "<reference name='root'><action method='setTemplate'><template>page/2columns-right.phtml</template></action></reference>";
        $update->addUpdate($xml);
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set layout for any specific category as per your requirement from admin.

Follow the steps:

Login to admin >> catalog >> Manage categories >> select your category >> custom design tab >> change page layout >> save category.

Answer (score 0):

The following setting should work:

Go to Admin >Manage categories >Select Category >Custom design then select

1. Page Layout to **2columns-right.phtml** and
2. In Custom Layout Update put the following code.

   ```
   <reference name="product.info">
     //put the child block here that you want call.
   </reference>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Found a much simpler solution, if you only need the change for a couple of products:

create a *fancy_name*.phtml file in *your_theme*/default/template/page/ (from copy of 1column-product.phtml or something).

Edit *fancy_name*.phtml until it becomes really fancy.

Go to magento backend, go to your product, go to design -> Custom layout update. Paste the following code and save:

```
<reference name="root">
    <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/fancy_name.phtml</template></action>
</reference>
```